# Using Neyman-Pearson Lemma to show that the most powerful test has critical region of the form:

Tags: statistics

A certain type of electronic component is susceptible to instantaneous failure at any time. The lifetime, T, of such as component can be modelled by an **exponential distribution with probability density function** 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta} ,  & t>0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$\theta$ is the expected lifetime of the components. $t_1,t_2,...,t_{81}$ are observed lifetimes for a random sample of size 81 of these components.

Consider testing the hypotheses $$H_0 : \theta = 10 \quad against \quad H_1 : \theta = 15 $$

Use the Neyman-Pearson Lemma to show that the most powerful test has critical region of the form 
$$\begin{cases}
t: \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{81} = \bar t > k 
\end{cases}$$

---

So far, I've got this:
According to my notes, the most powerful size $\alpha$ test has critical region: 
$$ C = t : \frac{\mathrm{L}(t;H_0)}{\mathrm{L}(t;H_1)} \le k $$

$ \mathrm{L}(\theta;t_1,...,t_{81}) 
 = \prod_{i=1}^{81} f(t_i,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{81} \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta} =  \frac{1}{\theta^{81}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{\theta}} $

Now If I were to let $\theta = H_0 \ and \ H_1$, I would just get this: 
$$  \frac{\frac{1}{10^{81}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{10}}}{ \frac{1}{15^{81}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{15}}} $$

Which doesn't really get me anywhere?
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is: reject if $\frac{\frac{1}{10^{81}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{10}}}{ \frac{1}{15^{81}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{15}}} \le k$ for some $k$ sufficiently small. Ultimately, $k$ will be determined by your null hypothesis, so I'll just reduce it to your "form" and then you explicitly find $k$ so that $P ( C \le k ; H_0) = \alpha$.

Multiplying by constants (and writing generic constant $k$ at each step) gives $\frac{e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{10}}}{ e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i}{15}}} \le k$, which means $e^{  x (- \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{15})}  \le k \iff e^{-x/30} \le k $, where $x = \sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i$.

Now, you ask for what values of $x$ is this satisfied -- i.e. when is $e^{-x/30}$ sufficiently small? The answer is for $x$ large, so our rejection region is $\sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i \ge k$ where $k$ is determined as above.

Also, dividing by sample size won't change inequalities, so this is the same as having rejection region $\frac{1}{81} \sum_{i=1}^{81} t_i \ge k$. You'll get the same answer either way.