# application of Neyman–Pearson Lemma

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that the distribution of lifetimes of TV tubes can be modelled by an exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$ so $f(x|\lambda)$ = $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ $e^\frac{-x}{\lambda}$, $x>0$. Under usual production conditions the mean lifetime is $50$ hours but if a fault occurs in the process the mean lifetime drops to $40$ hours
A random sample of $20$ tube lifetimes is to taken in order to test the hypothesis
$H_0:\lambda = 50$ vs $H_1:\lambda = 30$
and the following statistics is observed $\sum_{i=0}^n X_i = 680$.
Use Neyman–Pearson lemma to find the most powerful test with signficance level $\alpha = 0.05$.

My attempt was to start with the joint probability ratio under $H_0$ and $H_1$
$$\frac{\frac{1}{50^{20}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i}{50}}}{ \frac{1}{30^{20}}e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i}{30}}} .$$

We reject $H_0$ when $(\frac{1}{\lambda_1} -\frac{1}{\lambda_0}) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i <k$.

Since in the parenthesis we have a positive quantity should we reject $H_0$?

I do not understand the importance of the data $40$ since the alternative hypothesis is $30$ and not $40$.

Is this the right way to solve this exercise?
I am trying to understand Neyman–Pearson lemma and any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Have you looked at the several similar questions on this site? Here is one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2243491/321264. In your case, the rejection region is $\sum X_i<k$.

Comment: yes I have seen the many questions about it 
I wanted to understand the importance of the figure 40 given in the exercise text given that the alternative hypothesis is 30 and not 40 and the fact that the sum of Xi is known since $(\frac{1}{\lambda1}$ - $\frac{1}{\lambda0})$ is positive should we consider only $\sum_{i=0}^n Xi < K$ ?